# Where should i install Odoo erp on my CentOs device?

Tags: centos, odoo

Being a total newbie, I want to install Odoo on my CentOs device via cloning github repository. However, I am not certain about the installation directory I should choose. As you can see, the `ftp` directory is empty, shall I install it there?

[image]

Comment: Please check it --> https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html

Answer (score 0):

The installation folder is not too important as long as the permissions are opened for the user that will run the server.

Usually, it's installed under `/opt/odoo`

```
sudo mkdir /opt/odoo
cd /opt/odoo
sudo git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git
```